# How do I loop each line of a text file to print it using a windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following batch script to loop each line of a text file to print it but the only thing it's printed is the name of the text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET ServerList="serversRDPok.txt"
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=*" %%a in (%ServerList%) DO (
    echo line=%%a
)
endlocal
```

Comment: The reason is clearly explained, by reading the usage information for the command you're using. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented.

Comment: BTW, I'd appreciate some feedback for the answer I posted to assist you with your problem. Logging in when you have an active question, and not providing any indication that you've even done so, when someone has given their time to help you, is in my opinion, rude.

Answer (score 1):

The following command `SET ServerList="serversRDPok.txt"` is defining a variable named `ServerList` with the value `"serversRDPok.txt"`. If you take a look at the usage information for the `For` command, i.e. `for /?`, you'll note that including those doublequotes means that you're using this particular instruction, `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command`. It is treating your doublequoted value as a string. What you need is it treated as a doublequoted filename, and not a string.

To do that you need to incorporate the `UseBackQ` instruction.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set ServerList="serversRDPok.txt"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In (%ServerList%) Do (
    Echo line=%%G
)
```

Although you should really use the recommended syntax, `Set "VariableName=String Value"`, this particular method does not include the doublequotes as part of the name or value strings. Throughout your script, whenever you need to doublequote the value, you simply enclose the VariableName with doublequotes.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "ServerList=serversRDPok.txt"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In ("%ServerList%") Do (
    Echo line=%%G
)
```